# How to read text from clipboard with waiting list?

Tags: macos, keyboard, applescript, automator, reading-list

I ask you, please, if you could tell me how to read text from the clipboard with a waiting list?
I want to select text (which copies itself to the clipboard with the Auto Copy extension of the Chrome browser) and automatically reads the selected text while I am selecting several texts and reads the list of the texts that I was selecting?

I consult this because I have a family member with a disability who finds it more comfortable to select the text and automatically reads what he selects.

Can this be done with Automator?
Regards..

Comment: Did you try the Accessibility features which are part of standard macOS? As far as I know they offer the functionality to read selected text snippets and most likely are easier to set up and maintain than a home-grown solution?

Comment: Hi.
What Accessibility features does not allow me is to have a reading queue that continues reading the text successively as it is copied.
Accessibility features, only allows the reading of what is selected and to continue reading you have to wait for it to finish and select another text so that it starts reading that selected text.
I need this because it is for a person with a disability and it would be more comfortable for them to select the text and have them read in order of the text they selected.
Regards.

Comment: How exactly are these multiple selections made?  If they are selecting the text, are they not already reading it?  Or are you talking about the text being spoken?

Comment: Ah, so you want the user to be able to add new text parts to a reading queue while the previous ones are still being read?

Comment: @nohillside Yes it is. I need that. Since for the disabled person I want to help, it is easier for her to select the text with the mouse without having to press the keyboard. That is why the waiting queue is important, so that it automatically reads the text that it was selecting.
Regards.